# Error running hashcat commands

Tags: hash, hashcat

Ive recently downloaded the latest version of hashcat from github, and am not trying to run a basic bruteforce attach on the sample hashes provided.

However, despite reading the documentation I consistently get the following error, where ?a?a?a is changeable to the type of option I provide (And have no idea where Im going wrong):

For example the following command:

```
hashcat -a3 example0.hash ?a?a?a
```

Returns this:

```
zsh: no matches found: ?a?a?a
```

If I changed ?a?a?a with ?l?l, then the error would change to include this new parameter.

Ive tried many different variations to no avail. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: It may be that, depending on the environment in which you run the command, some characters need to be *escaped*, e.g. to avoid getting special treatment by the shell. What needs to be escape and how to escape it will be specific to the environment. For example, you may be able to enclose the argument in single or double quote.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me to put the mask in quotes, e.g.: `hashcat -m 1800 -a 3 -o ans.txt Target-Password.txt "?u?l?d?d?d?d"`

Answer (score 0):

`?a?a?a` is not a valid command.

Remove it and try, if that doesn't work then you should probably be specifying a `-m` so Hashcat knows which hash type it is. Also `-a0` is important for brute force attack mode. Remember Hashcat have their own community forums where you will get more in-depth answers as I am not too experienced with the tool.

Open CMD in correct location and:

```
$ hashcat64.exe -a0 -m0 example0.hash
```

Remember not to include '?a?a?a' as that is not a valid input for Hashcat, not sure where you found it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a couple things missing:

the -a3 is a mask attack. to do what I think you're trying to do and specify a mask on the command line, you need to define the charset **after** the -a 3 ie:
-a 3 -1 ?a

Then, you'll need to specify the hash type with -m

Then lastly, you'll need to specify your mask. So assuming the examples are ntlm, your command would look like:

```
hashcat64.exe -a 3 -1 ?a -m 1000 example0.hash ?1?1?1
```

It's thick reading, but the wiki is indispensable: https://hashcat.net/wiki/